# No exact matches in call to initializer of Text, how can I solve this issue in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new to swift, this might be a stupid question but it confuses me a long time.
Here is my code, I wrote this code by imitating the sandwich example from WWDC 2020's intro to swiftUI.

```
import SwiftUI

struct movieDetail: View {

    var idnum:Int

    var body: some View {

        Text(idnum)

    }
}

struct movieDetail_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {

        NavigationView {
            movieDetail(idnum:24428)
        }
       
    }
}
```

while it displays as compile error:

> No exact matches in call to initializer.

WWDC 2020's example is below

```
import SwiftUI

struct sandwichdetail: View {

    var sandwich:Sandwich
    @State private var zoomed = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text(sandwich.name)
        }
        .navigationTitle(sandwich.name)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
    }
}

struct sandwichdetail_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView{
            sandwichdetail(sandwich: testData[1])
        }
        
    }
}
```

I don't quite understand the difference between these 2 pieces of code and why mine fail and the sandwich example succeed displaying the sandwich's name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Text` type doesn't have an initializer that takes an `Int`. Try this instead:

```
Text("\(idnum)")
```

Comment: Great, it works, thanks a lot, I need to be more carful about these detail things

Answer (score 1):

Another more Swifty way, is using `description` because **Int** conforms to **CustomStringConvertible** protocol.

```
Text(idnum.description)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own initialiser for `Text` if this a common use case for you, using Swift's string interpolation. This may reduce type visibility at the call-site however.

```swift
extension Text {

    init(_ int: Int) {
        self = Text("\(int)")
    }

}
```